# Strange characters in pry output

Tags: ruby, debugging, rspec, pry

When debugging, pry is outputting weird characters on the command line within a specific project that i'm working on. The weird thing is, when I open up a different project, pry works just fine.

Example:

# lib/a.rb

```
require 'pry'

def some_method
 binding.pry
 # some code...
 # more code...
end
```

After running my specs, I get the following output on the command-line:

```
  3413: 31def 34some_method 
=>3414: binding.pry
  3415: 3232some code...
  3416: 34more code...
  3417: 31end
```

The line numbers are supposed to be: 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 respectively.

Also, while in the pry console, if I type 'hello', I get the following output.

From this:

```
pry(#<MyModule::MyClass>)> 'hello'
```

To this:

```
pry(#<MyModule::MyClass>)> 3232'3232he3232'32
=> 3232"3232he3232"32
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Pry is trying to show you colored output and reformat previous lines, but it looks like your terminal doesn't support it. You can [disable colored output](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#wiki-Config_color) with:

```
toggle-color
```

If that works and you'd like it to stay that way, you can add this line to a `.pryrc` file:

```
Pry.config.color = false
```

Your other project may already have one, which would explain why you aren't having problems there.

Comment: Thanks, Ash. The weird things is that pry was working perfectly in this particular project before, outputting colors without a problem. The terminal I'm using is iTerm2. Any thoughts?